# How do I get a list of only the files (not the directories) from a package?

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg, find

Using `dpkg -L <package name>` I am able to obtain a list of all the files from a package, but it contains a list of directories as well, which I want to exclude.

So, for example:

```
dpkg -L elixir
```

gives me:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/elixir
/usr/lib/elixir/bin
/usr/lib/elixir/bin/elixir
/usr/lib/elixir/bin/elixirc
/usr/lib/elixir/bin/iex
/usr/lib/elixir/bin/mix
/usr/lib/elixir/lib
/usr/lib/elixir/lib/eex
/usr/lib/elixir/lib/eex/ebin
/usr/lib/elixir/lib/eex/ebin/Elixir.EEx.Compiler.beam
(etc...)
```

I have tried excluding the directories with the following:

```
dpkg -L elixir |  find  -maxdepth 1 -not -type d
```

But that just gives the file in the current directory.

Piping the `dpkg` output to `ls` with `xargs` also does not seem to allow me to filter out directories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply [loop](https://www.shellscript.sh/loops.html) over each line of `dpkg -L elixir` and [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(Unix)) whether the line is the path of a [regular file](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/regular-file.htm), then `echo` it:

```
while read f; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done < <(dpkg -L elixir)
```

Your idea with `find` looks good but `find`

1. does not accept stdin and
2. searches in the given path while you want to just check properties of the single given path,

so it’s not the right tool here.

Answer (score 11):

It should be possible with `xargs` plus a shell test, for example

```
dpkg -L elixir | xargs sh -c 'for f; do [ -d "$f" ] || echo "$f"; done'
```

Answer (score 5):

With perl oneliner:

```
dpkg -L elixir | perl -nE 'chomp; say unless -d'
```

- `dpkg -L` will list all files/directories in package and output it to *stdout*
- `perl -nE` will iterate following perl code over each line of `dpkg` output, leaving current line in default argument variable (called `$_`)
- `chomp` removes trailing linefeed from *stdin*, thus leaving only filename in default argument variable (`$_`).
- `say` is short for `say $_`, which will print to *stdout* default argument if following condition is true.
- `unless -d` (short for `unless -d $_`) is condition for previous `say`, and means it will only be true if **specified filename is not a directory**

So, it will display all filenames which are not directories. If you wanted to display only directories, you would replace `unless` with `if`. Or if you wanted only symlinks, you could use `-l` instead of `-d`, etc. (see `man perlfunc` for more details)

Comment: This is my new favorite :)

Comment: I really like this.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to compare the output of `dpkg` with the results of `find` for files:

```
comm -12 \
   <(dpkg -L kate | sort ) \
   <(find $( dpkg -L kate ) -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort )
```